# Would it be feasible for a single planet to have both magma based volcanoes and cryovolcanos?

Tags: volcanoes

I took astronomy class last semester, and I became aware that there were not only magma based volcanoes, but ones run on colder moons in our solar system, called cryovolcanos that in essence spew extremely cold water mixed with ammonia. If the planet is closer to the sun, say, third, or fourth, in a solar system like ours, would a planet be likely to only form one type of volcanism? I was hoping to include it in my original world, with my icy, southern continent having a large shield-like volcano, run by cryovolcanism, while on a hotter continent, having the typical composite volcanoes along the plate boundaries.

Or is this too broad a question?

Answer (score 9):

We have hydrovolcanoes on earth.

[image: steamboat geyser]
http://www.kotatv.com/content/news/Worlds-largest-geyser-erupts-again-in-Yellowstone-482584191.html

Steamboat geyser erupts hot water, like some cryovolcanoes.  Like the cryovolcanos a lot of that water then freezes, if it is winter.  It is smaller than a volcano but I do not see why you can't scale it up.
You can have one source of energy for the volcanoes but have different things erupt.  If it shoots only water we call it a geyser but volcanoes can put out lava, fine ash, lahar mud (which means water too), or gas.  Since it is unclear what powers the cryovolcanoes (as far as I can tell from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryovolcano)) you can power them the same way as the regular ones.

I am not sure about a shield cryovolcano.   The shield on a shield volcano is made of the accumulated lava.  Unless you had the shield be made of ice, which would be neat.  You could have it slowly move away as a glacier, replenished by the eruptions on top.